# Correct json parsing but cant find string

Tags: arrays, swift

I am decoding a json file from google maps api.
The struct for parsing looks fine.

```
// MARK: - Welcome
struct POIData: Codable {
    let results: [Result]

}

// MARK: - Result
struct Result: Codable {
    let geometry: Geometry
    let name: String
    let place_id: String
    let photos: [Photo]
}

// MARK: - Geometry
struct Geometry: Codable {
    let location: Location
}

// MARK: - Location
struct Location: Codable {
    let lat, lng: Double
}

// MARK: - Photo
struct Photo: Codable {
    let photoReference: String
}
```

But as soon as I want to parse the photoReference my code says `Value of type '[Photo]' has no member 'photoReference'.`

This works:

```
cell.cellText.text = searchApi.dataFromSearchApi[indexPath.row].name
```

This not:

```
cell.cellCategory.text = searchApi.dataFromSearchApi[indexPath.row].photos.photoReference
```

How is that even possible?

Added JSON:

```
"results": [
    {
      "name": "xxx",
      "opening_hours": {
        "open_now": true
      },
      "photos": [
        {
          "height": 900,
          "html_attributions": [
            "<a href=\"h"
          ],
          "photo_reference": "Axxx",
          "width": 1600
        }
      ],
      "place_id": "xxxx",
    .
```

Comment: Look at the error message closely, what type is an `[Photo]`? Or given your code samples, compare it to what type `results` is.

Comment: Well its an Array. The same as [Result]. But I can access to name in [Result] but not to photoReference in [Photo].

Comment: Isn’t the difference obvious, in the first example you have an index you can use so you are actually accessing a single element in the array. You need to come up with another solution for the `photos` property and what that solution is depends solely on what it is you want to achieve.

Comment: I added the response from the json request. I just want to achieve to get the string for photo reference.

Comment: It’s already clear what the issue is so the json isn’t needed. Unless you explain what you want to be displayed in that cell we can’t help you.

Comment: I want to get to the value of photoreference which is a string. But I cannot access it because it gives me the error above.

Comment: _"...the value of photoreference which is a string"_, but it isn't one string since it is inside an array so it is zero or more strings. You know the difference between one and many so how can you not understand it here? If you believe the `photos` array always contains only one element then you could use `.first` perhaps.

Comment: I understood now what you meant. It took me a while.         cell.cellCategory.text = searchApi.dataFromSearchApi[indexPath.row].photos[0].photo_reference
 that my solution which works. Thank you!

Comment: `photos[0]`, this will lead to a crash if the array is empty. Better to use `first` instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Array** of **photos** requires an index to retrieve a specific photoReference.

Example:

```
searchApi.dataFromSearchApi[indexPath.row].photos.first?.photoReference
```

Comment: This code is not correct, `first` returns an optional so add a `?`