# Showing a popup within a cell in tableView

Tags: swift, class, struct, tableview

I have a struct file where I process data from a json file and want to show a popup if the decoded results are nil or similar.

But I noticed that I cannot show a popup within a cell or a struct. So how can I solve this problem? I guess I have to declare the function inside the class where the tableView is located but how can I access the function inside my struct?

struct searchApi:

```
     ...
        func newParseJSON(poiData: Data, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            do {
                let decodedData = try decoder.decode(POIData.self, from: poiData)
                searchApi.dataFromSearchApi = decodedData.results
                
                func displayAlert() {
                          let dialogMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Json Empty", message: "....", preferredStyle: .alert)
                          let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
                              print("Ok button tapped")
                          })
                          dialogMessage.addAction(ok)
                          self.present(dialogMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)
                          
                      }
                
//set condition for showing displayAlert
                displayAlert()
        
                completionHandler() // Call the completion handler when data is parsed
                
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
            
        }...
```

My other class is called: class SearchPoi

Comment: I think you're requesting in background thread and UIAlertController can not be displayed in background. Try to wrap it into `DispatchQueue.main`. In my opinion, i think you should throw an error and then catch it instead of nested func like above.

Comment: Having UI code in your parsing method is not a good approach. The parsing method should only parse the data and return either the result or an error. Let the caller decided how to handle the error (such as displaying an alert).

Comment: put this in the function displayAlert: `assert(Thread.isMainThread)`. Does it crash?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing asynchronous about your code so no completion handler is needed here.

Assuming you have the same types as in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76793265/correct-json-parsing-but-cant-find-string) the function can be rewritten either as

```
func newParseJSON(poiData: Data) throws -> [Result] {
    try JSONDecoder().decode(POIData.self, from: poiData).results
}
```

as I prefer or If you want to use `self` as in the question

```
func newParseJSON(poiData: Data) throws {
    searchApi.dataFromSearchApi = try JSONDecoder().decode(POIData.self, from: poiData).results
}
```

Then you handle the error and present any error message where you call this function instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
//MARK:ShowAlert
func showAlertMsg(Message: String, AutoHide:Bool) -> Void {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: Message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        
        if AutoHide == true
        {
            //alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
            let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(2)
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime) {
                print("Alert Dismiss")
                alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
        }
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

    enter code here
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Please [edit] your answer and explain what was wrong and how your code fixes the problem.

Comment: `UIApplication keyWindow` is deprecated as of iOS 13.0. This code won't work with scene support. And such an answer shouldn't be used. Non-UI code should not be showing an alert.